# How to catch the selected date changed event in calendar?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I need to fire the date selected by an user for perform a research in a database. The caller class isn't the MainWindow class but rather an external class called Fixtures, and read objects GUI call the manufacturer via a variable. 
For example, in this case to access the calendar execute:

```
MainWindow.AppWindow.Calendar;
```

How can I see if a date has been selected by a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something when selected date changes, the Calendar control has a `SelectedDatesChanged` event. Add an event handler method for this event.

XAML:

```
<Calendar SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_OnSelectedDatesChanged"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Calendar_OnSelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

It sounds like your question might be around object scope in C#. Needs further explanation

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a *DatePicker* instead of a Calendar and listen for the following event SelectedDateChanged.

You could try and listen for the *DisplayDateChanged* event for the Calendar class and do something when the date changes.

Comment: I must use the Calendar, I can't change now.